# What is the distance allowed for the goalkeeper to be off the line during penalty kick?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

Recently, I saw a video showing a penalty kick replayed twice because the goalkeeper advanced from the goal line.

My question is: what is the distance allowed for the goalkeeper to be off the line during a penalty kick? And generally, have these kind of incidences happened before?

Comment: Since 2016, [this offence is now a mandatory caution (yellow card)](http://theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-offences-and-sanctions). Since referees don't like giving soft cautions, you can now expect the enforcement of this rule to be even more lax than it already was.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [IFAB Laws of the Game, Law 14 - The Penalty Kick, 1. Procedure](http://theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure):

> The defending **goalkeeper must remain on the goal line**, facing the
>   kicker, between the goalposts until the ball has been kicked.

These kind of incidences actually happen quite rarely, the famous one being [Bill Hamid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Hamid) of D.C. United saving 2 attempts from penalty kick in the game against Portland Timbers but both being overruled by the referee. Here's the [**video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erdYfgregHs).